# Showing Paragraphs in ToC in tex4ht

Tags: sectioning, tex4ht, sections-paragraphs

I've been fiddling with this for three hours and I feel so lost because it seems like nothing I do has any effect on the tex4ht generated html.

I have a fairly large document that I'm building as a pdf using pdflatex as well as for html using tex4ht.

I have a few html requirements:

- Front page ToC with sections and subsections.
- Numbered paragraphs.
- Section page ToC with subsection, subsubsections, and paragraphs.
- Paragraph headings on a new line.

In pdf I have the same requirements as html, but I don't need the third. I have fulfilled the first two requirements, I'm just missing the final one but that's a bonus question. I want to focus on the tex4ht things.

I currently have the front page ToC with sections and subsections using 
`\Configure{tableofcontents*}{section,subsection}`. I have numbered paragraphs using `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`. I can't for the life of me get the others to work.

Here is my raw cfg file: https://pastebin.com/64ECC1G6

Answer (score 2):

Try these configurations for the paragraphs:

```
\Configure{paragraph}{}{}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<h4 class="paragraphHead">}\TitleMark\space}{\HCode{</h4>}\IgnoreIndent}
\ConfigureMark{paragraph}{\theparagraph}
\Css{.paragraphToc{margin-left:6em;}}
```

The `\Configure{paragraph}` configures paragraph, the `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` takes care of closing paragraphs, `\TitleMark` prints the paragraph number and `\IgnoreIndent` disables indent for the next text paragraph.

`\ConfigureMark{paragraph}{\theparagraph}` enables `\theparagraph` counter to be available in the `\TitleMark`.

The CSS code configures indentation in the TOC.

Sample result:

[image]

Comment: I was hopeful, but no dice. Is there anything I can send you that would help debug this?

Comment: @Braaedy just send it to my mail (michal.h21@gmail.com)